# Serial data reading from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to capture my temperature sensor reading from Arduino Uno, turn on AC if temperature is high or off and then send temperature to Raspberry Pi and write to a log file.

My Python code in Raspberry Pi to capture event and log to a file.

```
import time
import datetime
import serial

now = datetime.datetime.now()
month=time.strftime("%Y_%m")

#f= open(month+".txt","w+")
f=open("temperature.log","w+")

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) # enable the serial port
print 'before while'
while 1: # execute the loop forever
    val=ser.readline()
    # read the serial data sent by the UNO
    f.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
# print the serial data sent by UNO
    f.write(' -> ')
    f.write(val)
f.close()
```

I can get the temperature value (sometimes it's a mess **16707**), but most importantly it does not write to the log file.

Where am I missing? Do I have to include another library in the Python code?

Comment: Could it be, that you are stucking in the while loop? I mean "while 1:" should mean "run this thing to the rest of your life" and your logfile writing isn't part of the loop. Or is it just the question editing, thats a little bit messed?

Comment: @H.Puc Yes, It was a mistake, fixed it. But still does not get the log details.

Comment: look up MCVE. If your problem is about writing to a log file we don't need to see your arduino code

Comment: @flakes yes, but keeping it won't do any damage either.

Comment: @Sachith actually it does a fair bit of damage! Generally, longer questions get less attention because they require more effort from the readers. People don't want to spend the time debugging parts of your code that aren't the problem. If its just a few lines of code, a lot of people will actually compile and run it. Any more than that and most people wont deep-dive on your question. Shorter questions also helps people who might know the answer see the problem faster-- making someone who might just be browsing casually actually respond to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the log file at the end of each loop.  It should run once, but after the file is closed, it won't write again until you open it.  Just put `f.close()` after the while loop.  Or as a better practice:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
with open("temperature.log", "w+") as f:
    print 'before while'
    while 1:
        val = ser.readline()
        f.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
        f.write(' -> ')
        f.write(val)
```

This will close the file automatically once the code inside the `with` statement is finished.

Comment: Yes, tried it too. Still no luck, process is running as a `nohup` process.

Comment: Hmm, maybe add a `print val` in the loop just to debug?

Comment: Also done, the problem is this does not run constantly. One time retrieve is working fine.

Comment: What data type does `now.strftime` return?  maybe add a `str` to each write statement

Comment: `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'str'`